# Movie about a giant robot

Tags: identify-this-movie

Please help me to identify the movie those pictures belong to.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks like the giant robot from [The Day the Earth Stood Still](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0970416/), a remake of the 1951 film with the same name. The 2008 remake stars Keanu Reeves and Jennifer Connelly;

[image: Poster The Day The Eart Stood Still (Wikipedia)]

The robot's name is [GORT, which is short for Genetically Organised Robotic Technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gort_%28The_Day_the_Earth_Stood_Still%29).

[image: image of GORT]